# Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>

Tags: java

Добрый день мне необходимо подсчитать суммарную зарплату сотрудников по подразделениям. Данные я загружаю из csv файла. Для подсчёта суммарной з/п по подразделениям я использую Stream API. Версия java 8.
Вот код моего метода:

```
public void oneMethod()
        {
            List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
            Map<String, Integer> nameSalary=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
          //  nameSalary=r.toList().stream().flatMap(x->Stream.of(x.getDivision().getName(),x.getSalary())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

           ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));
             ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));

            list1=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

            Map<IDivision, Double> countDivisionSalary = r.toList().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision, Collectors.summarizingDouble(IPerson::getSalary)));
            for (Map.Entry entry : countDivisionSalary.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Podrazdelenie: " + entry.getKey()+"Sum Salary"+entry.getValue());
        }
```

На этой строчке    Map nameSalary=new HashMap();
Java  выбивает следующее исключение:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type:

Код класса LoadRepository в котором происходит загрузка в csv файл
(он также содержит метод oneMethod для подсчёта суммарной з/п по подразделениям):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javafx.util.Pair;

/**
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class LoadRepository {

    private Repository r;
    private int size=2000;

    public Repository getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(Repository r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public LoadRepository() {
        r=new Repository(size);
    }



    public void readFromFileInRepository(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
       // Repository r = new Repository(2000);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        File f = new File(fileName);
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

        String line;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            String buf = in.nextLine();
            if (buf.startsWith("id")) {
                ;
            } else {
                String[] bufArray = buf.split(";");

                int id = Integer.parseInt(bufArray[0]);
                String firstName = bufArray[1];
                String lastName = bufArray[2];
                Gender gender = Gender.valueOf(bufArray[3].toUpperCase());
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(bufArray[4], formatter);

                String Name = bufArray[5];

                IDivision div = new Division(Name);

                BigDecimal money = new BigDecimal(bufArray[6]);

                IPerson bufObject = new Person(id, firstName, lastName, gender, date, div, money);

                if (bufObject != null) {
                    r.add(bufObject);
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public Stream<IPerson> threeMethod()
    {
       return r.toList().stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("aa"));
       //stream.filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("AA"));
       //return stream;

    }

      public Stream<IPerson> twoMethod()
    {
        BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal(5000);
       return r.toList().stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("a")).filter(s->s.getAge()>30).filter(s->s.getSalary().compareTo(valDouble)<0);
       //stream.filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("AA"));
       //return stream;

    }

        public   Map<Integer, Long> fourMethod()
    {
       // BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal(5000);
      // return r.toList().stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("a")).filter(s->s.getAge()>30).filter(s->s.getSalary().compareTo(valDouble)<0);
       //stream.filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("AA"));
       //return stream;
     //  Map<Integer,Integer> hm= new HashMap<>();
     //  HashMap<int,int>= r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson,0));
    // hm.put(r.toList().stream().filter(s->s.getBirthdate().getYear()>0), size);
 Set<Integer> set1=new HashSet<Integer>();
 Set<Integer> set2=new HashSet<Integer>();

 List<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();

 set1=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
 list1=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).collect(Collectors.toList());

       r.toList().stream().filter(s->s.getBirthdate().getYear()==s.getBirthdate().getYear()).count();

    //    r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear());

//   Set<Integer> duplicated = r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).filter(i -> Collections.frequency(r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()), i) >1)
               // .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  /* System.out.println("Years:");
   for(int i:set1) System.out.println(i);
   System.out.println("Count of years:");
    for(int i:duplicated) System.out.println(i);*/
  /*Map<Integer, Integer> yearDuplicates = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  yearDuplicates.put(r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()), r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).count());
  System.out.println("Years duplicates:");
    for (Map.Entry entry : yearDuplicates.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Year: " + entry.getKey() + " Count: "
        + entry.getValue());
}*/
 // Map<Integer, Integer> letterToCount =
          // list1.stream().collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
         // return r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum));
/*    Set<Integer> set3=   set2.stream()
       .filter(t -> Collections.frequency(r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()), t) > 1).collect(Collectors.toSet());*/
     /*   System.out.println("Count years");
       for(int i:set3) System.out.println(i);*/



       Map<Integer, Long> countForYear = list1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));




       /*for (Map.Entry entry : countForYear.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Year: " + entry.getKey() + " Count: "
        + entry.getValue());

    }*/
        return countForYear;




}
        public void oneMethod()
        {
            List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
            Map<String, Integer> nameSalary=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
          //  nameSalary=r.toList().stream().flatMap(x->Stream.of(x.getDivision().getName(),x.getSalary())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

           ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));
             ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));

            list1=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

            Map<IDivision, Double> countDivisionSalary = r.toList().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision, Collectors.summarizingDouble(IPerson::getSalary)));
            for (Map.Entry entry : countDivisionSalary.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Podrazdelenie: " + entry.getKey()+"Sum Salary"+entry.getValue());
        }

}
}
```

Код класса Person - в нём фигурируют поля IDivision(ссылка на интерфейс IDivision который реализует класс Division):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import org.joda.time.Period;

/**
 * Class Person contains four field: 1) id as identifikator; 2) Name-Name Father
 * Surname; 3) date - date birthday 4) sex - sex Person
 *
 * Methods getDate(),getSex(),getId(), getName() -returns values fields class
 * Methods setDate(),setSex(),setId(), setName() -set values fields class
 *
 * Method difference_date() -calcute age Person
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class Person implements IPerson {

    /**
     * Filed "id" as identifikator.
     *
     */
    private int id;

    /**
     * Filed "Name"-Name Father Surname.
     *
     */


    private String FirstName;

    private String LastName;

    private LocalDate Birthdate;

    /**
     * Filed date - date birthday.
     *
     */


    /**
     * Filed Gender - sex Person.
     *
     */


    private Gender Gender;

    /**
     * Filed Salary - Salary for Person.
     *
     */

    private BigDecimal Salary;

    public IDivision IDivision;





    /**
     * Method getId() return Id.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }



    /**
     * Method setId set field Id.
     *
     * @param id
     */
    public final void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




 /**
     * Method getFirstName return filedt FirstName.
     *

     */

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    /**
     * Method getFirstName set filed FirstName.
     *
     * @param FirstName
     */

    public String setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        return this.FirstName;

    }

    /**
     * Method getlastName return filed LastName.
     *

     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    /**
     * Method setLastName set filed LastName.
     *
     * @param FirstName
     */
    public String setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
        return this.LastName;
    }
/**
     * Method getBirthdate return filed Birthdate.
     *

     */
    public LocalDate getBirthdate() {
        return Birthdate;
    }

     /**
     * Method setBirthdate set filed Birthdate.
     *
     * @param Birthdate

     */
    public LocalDate setBirthdate(LocalDate Birthdate) {
        this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
        return this.Birthdate;
    }

    /**
     * Method getSalary return filed Salary.
     *

     */
    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }

    /**
     * Method setSalary set filed Salary.
     *
     * @param Salary
     */
    public void setSalary(BigDecimal Salary) {
        this.Salary = Salary;
    }

     /**
     * Method getGender return  gender Person.
     *

     */
    public Gender getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

     /**
     * Method setGender set gender Person.
     *
     * @param Gender
     */
    public void setGender(Gender Gender) {
        this.Gender = Gender;
    }

    /**
     * Method getDivision return gender Person.
     *
     */
    public IDivision getDivision() {
        return IDivision;
    }


    /**
     * Method getDivision return field setDivision.
     *
     * @param division
     */
    public void setDivision(IDivision division) {
        this.IDivision = IDivision;
    }

    /**
     * This is constructor.
     *
     * @param id
     * @param FirstName
     * @param Name
     * @param Birthdate
     * @param Gender
     * @param Salary
     *
     */
    public Person(int id, String FirstName, String LastName, Gender Gender,LocalDate Birthdate,  String Name, BigDecimal Salary) {

        this.id = id;

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
         this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Birthdate = Birthdate;


        this.IDivision.setName(Name);
        this.Salary = Salary;

    }

    public Person(int id, String FirstName, String LastName,Gender Gender, LocalDate Birthdate, IDivision IDivision, BigDecimal Salary ) {
        this.id = id;

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
        this.IDivision = IDivision;
        this.Salary = Salary;

    }



    /**
     * Method getAge calculate and print age Person.
     */
    public Integer getAge() {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

       //Period p = new Period(date, now);

        int years = (int) ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(Birthdate, now);

        return years;
    }

}
```

Код класса Division:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;

/**
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class Division implements IDivision {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Division( String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Код класса Repository(в нём используется метод toList(), который преобразует массив объектов класса Person  в коллекцию):

```
package com.mycompany.laba1;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

import org.joda.time.format.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Class Repository is intended for store objects class IPerson.
 *
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class Repository implements IRepository {

    /**
     * Field size store size massiv.
     */
    private int size;

    private IPerson[] mass;

    private int count = 0;

    /**
     * This is constructor. In constructor we initialize property size and array
     * mass of type IPerson
     *
     *
     * @author Data
     * @param size
     */
    public Repository(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        mass = new IPerson[size];
    }

    /**
     * Method setSize set size.
     *
     * @param size
     */
    public final void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    /**
     * Method getSize return size.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public final int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * Method add -add Object into array mass.
     *
     */
    public void add(IPerson person) {

        /* if (count == size)
        {
        int currentCapacity = mass.length;
        IPerson[] tempArr = new IPerson[currentCapacity + currentCapacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            tempArr[i] = mass[i];
        }
        mass = tempArr;
        }*/
        int firstLength = mass.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {

            if (mass[i] != null && i == mass.length - 1) {
                int currentCapacity = mass.length;
                IPerson[] tempArr = new IPerson[currentCapacity * 2];
                for (int j = 0; j < currentCapacity; j++) {
                    tempArr[j] = mass[j];
                }
                // mass = new IPerson[tempArr.length];
                mass = tempArr;

                //    mass[currentCapacity]=obj;
                //   break;
            }
            if (mass[i] == null) {
                mass[i] = person;
                break;
            }

        }

        //else
    }

    /**
     * Method add -add Object into array mass, if element mass[index] is null.
     *
     */
    public void add(int index, IPerson person) {
        if (mass[index] == null) {
            mass[index] = person;
        } else //throw new Exception("This index contains element");
        {
            Optional.of("This index contains element");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method set -replace element array "mas" with "index" for object "person".
     *
     * @param index
     * @param person
     */
    public IPerson set(int index, IPerson person) {
        mass[index] = person;
        return person;

    }

    /**
     * Method get -return element array "mass" for given "index".
     *
     */
    public IPerson get(int index) {
        return mass[index];
    }

    /**
     * Method toList -convert array "mass" to Collection "List".
     *
     */
    public List<IPerson> toList() {
        ArrayList<IPerson> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            if (mass[i] != null) {
                arr.add(mass[i]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    /**
     * Method delete(int index) receive index element massiv and delete this
     * element.
     *
     * @param index
     */
    public IPerson delete(int index) {

    /*   int size2 = mass.length - 1;
        IPerson[] mass2 = new IPerson[size2];
        System.arraycopy(mass, 0, mass2, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(mass, index + 1, mass2, index,
                mass.length - index - 1);

        //   count--;
        mass = new IPerson[size2];
        System.arraycopy(mass2, 0, mass, 0, size2);
        mass[index+1]=null;*/

     /*  for (int i = index; i < mass.length-1; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = mass[i + 1];
        }
        int[] newArr = new int[mass.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(mass, 0, newArr, 0, mass.length - 1);*/

       // return mass[index];
        IPerson oldValue = mass[index];

    int numMoved = count - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(mass, index+1, mass, index, numMoved);
    }

    mass[--count] = null;
    return oldValue;

    }

    /**
     * Method getMass - return array "mass"
     *
     */
    public IPerson[] getMass() {

        int countNotNullElement = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            if (mass[i] != null) {
                countNotNullElement++;
            }
        }

        int currentIndex = 0;

        IPerson[] mass2 = new IPerson[countNotNullElement];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {

            if (mass[i] != null) {
                mass2[currentIndex++] = mass[i];
            }

        }
        // mass=mass2;

        return mass2;
    }

    /**
     * Method readFromFileInRepository - read file and add to array "mass" with
     * method add(IPerson obj)
     *
     * @param fileName
     */

    /**
     * Method SortBy-sort array "mass" with given comparator
     *
     * @param comparator
     */
    public void sortBy(Comparator<IPerson> comparator) {
       /* BubbleSorter bs=new BubbleSorter();
        try {
            bs.bubbleSort(comparator);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }*/

        InsertionSorter is=new InsertionSorter();
        try {
            is.insertionSort(Comparators.salary);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Repository.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

     public void bubbleSort(Comparator<IPerson> comparator) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = mass.length-1 ; j > i; j--) {
                        if (comparator.compare(mass[j-1], mass[j])>0) {
                            IPerson buf = mass[j - 1];
                            mass[j - 1] = mass[j];
                            mass[j] = buf;
                        }

                    }
                }

    }

      public void insertionSort(Comparator<IPerson> comparator) {
       IPerson temp;
                int item;
                for (int counter = 1; counter < mass.length; counter++) {
                    temp = mass[counter];
                    item = counter - 1;
                    while (item >= 0 && comparator.compare(mass[item], temp)>0) {
                        mass[item + 1] = mass[item];
                        mass[item] = temp;
                        item--;
                    }
                }

    }



    public IRepository searchBy(Predicate<IPerson> condition) {
        IRepository buf = new Repository(size);

         IDivision div = new Division("A");
        IDivision div2 = new Division("B");
        IDivision div3 = new Division("C");

        // System.out.println("Hello World");
        LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.MAY, 14);
        LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.of(1965, Month.MAY, 14);
        LocalDate localDate3 = LocalDate.of(1970, Month.MAY, 14);

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(20000);
        BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(25000);
        BigDecimal bd3 = new BigDecimal(35000);

        IPerson p1 = new Person(1, "Valeriy", "Petrov",Gender.MALE, localDate1,  div, bd);

        IPerson p2 = new Person(5, "Valeriy", "Petrov",Gender.MALE, localDate1,  div, bd);

        IPerson p3 = new Person(6, "Valeriy", "Petrov",Gender.MALE, localDate1,  div2, bd);
        IPerson p4 = new Person(7, "Valeriy", "Petrov",  Gender.MALE,localDate2, div, bd);
        IPerson p5 = new Person(8, "Valeriy", "Petrov", Gender.MALE,localDate1,  div, bd);
        IPerson p6 = new Person(9, "Vera", "Petrova",Gender.FEMALE, localDate1,  div3, bd2);
        IPerson p7 = new Person(10, "Ivan", "Ivanov", Gender.MALE,localDate3,  div, bd);
        IPerson p8 = new Person(0, "Vladimir", "Smirnov",Gender.MALE, localDate1,  div, bd3);

        buf.add(p1);
        buf.add(p2);
        buf.add(p3);
        buf.add(p4);



        for (int i = 0; i < buf.toList().size(); i++) {
            if (condition.test(mass[i])) {
                return buf;
            }
        }
        return buf;

    }

}
```

Вот как выглядит загружаемый  csv файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: Используется NetBeans IDE?

Comment: да NetBeans IDE 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans позволяет запускать код, даже если некоторые классы не компилируются. Это, правда, приводит к неприятным эффектам, когда пытаемся обратиться к не скомпилированному классу, конкретно, к `Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type`.

Попробуй отключить настройку "Compile on save" в свойствах проекта (Build -> Compiling).

Так же ошибка могла быть вызвана кешированием. Ниже ссылка на англоязычное обсуждение этой ошибки - много дельных советов:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this

И да, код вообще компилируется?

Comment: Да код компилируется.

Comment: Тогда попробуй приведённые рекомендации, должно помочь